# need to get an external button to link to maps when clicked on

Tags: google-maps

I need help linking buttons to cities. When clicked, opens a new map which then zooms in and I can have places of interest also. This is my file below and I am not the best at coding so help appreciated please.

I haven't included the HTML file as its so basic and was more what I needed to add here.

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: {
            lat: 50.7436337,
            lng: 18.4208039
        }
    });
```

to loop around

Need help to link buttons to cities that when clicked upon opens up to a map of that city

```
var labels = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

My places are outlined below of the cities I want in my buttons:

```
function addMarker(feature) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        map: map,
        icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
    });
}
```

The map of the world:

```
var map;
var InforObj = [];
var centerCords = {
    lat: 50.7436337, 
    lng: 18.4208039
};
var markersOnMap = [{
    placeName: "Amsterdam (Johan Cryuff Arena)",
    LatLng: [{
        lat: 52.314371,
        lng: 4.941964
   }],
},
{   placeName: "Baku (Olympic Stadium)",
    LatLng: [{
        lat: 40.4300,
        lng: 49.9196
    }]
},
{   placeName: "Bilbao (San Mames)",
    LatLng: [{
        lat: 43.2641,
        lng: -2.9494
    }]
},
{   placeName: "Bucharest (Arena Nationala)",
    LatLng: [{
        lat: 44.437139,
        lng: 26.152579
    }]
},
{   placeName: "Budapest (Puskas Arena)",
    LatLng: [{
        lat: 47.503172,
        lng: 19.097022
    }]
},
{   placeName: "Copenhagen (Parken Stadium)",
    LatLng: [{
        lat: 55.702701,
        lng: 12.572433
    }]
},
{   placeName: "Dublin (Aviva Stadium)",
    LatLng: [{
        lat: 53.335232,
        lng: -6.228457
    }]
},
{   placeName: "Glasgow (Hampden Park)",
    LatLng: [{
        lat: 55.825842,
        lng: -4.252048
    }]
},
{   placeName: "London (Wembley Stadium)",
    LatLng: [{
        lat: 51.556021,
        lng: -0.279519
    }]
},
{   placeName: "Munich (Allianz Arena)",
    LatLng: [{
        lat: 48.2188,
        lng: 11.624707
    }]
},
{   placeName: "Rome (Stadio Olimpico)",
    LatLng: [{
        lat: 41.934077,
        lng: 12.454725
    }]
},
{   placeName: "Saint Petersburg (Krestovsky Stadium)",
    LatLng: [{
        lat: 59.972728,
        lng: 30.221405
    }]
},
];
```

List of the cities above:

```
window.onload = function () {
   initMap();
};

function addMarkerInfo() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markersOnMap.length; i++) {
        var contentString = '<div id="content"><h1>' + markersOnMap[i].placeName +
            '</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix mutat posse suscipit id, vel ea tantas omittam detraxit.</p></div>';
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markersOnMap[i].LatLng[0],
            map: map,
        });
        const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString,
            maxWidth: 200
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function () {
            closeOtherInfo();
            infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
            InforObj[0] = infowindow;
        });
    }
}
```

All part of the same code and I am not sure how its done properly

```
function closeOtherInfo() {
    if (InforObj.length > 0) {
        // detach the info-window from the marker ... undocumented in the API docs 
        InforObj[0].set("marker", null);
        // and close it 
        InforObj[0].close();
        // blank the array 
        InforObj.length = 0;
    }
}

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom: 4,
       center: centerCords
    });
    addMarkerInfo();
}

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1293954, 12.556663), //Setting Initial Position
        zoom: 10
    });
}
```

my file path

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
    });
}
```

This is my javascript code

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to show all of the stadia on the same map and click on one to move the map center; or do you want to have buttons outside of the map that, when clicked, will move the map center to be the stadium; or do you want each button to open a brand new map with only that stadium labelled on it?

Comment: oh first of all thanks so much for replying. i have a map set up currently which shows my markers of the 12 football stadiums across europe so I have 12 buttons outside the map that if you click on say Dublin or London, it will zoom in on that location and I can add place of interest around it or I would go for what you said on last line it will open a brand new map. I am open to whatever is best.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to fix your formatting. Please learn about formatting and do that  yourself on the next question. You may need to [edit] this question if I messed up something. Please also read [ask] and try to trim down your code to a [mcve]. Don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially, code is unreadable in comments, and comments are ordered by votes, not chronologically.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Much appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle or jsbin with your full code so that we can reproduce your existing map implementation and understand better what you need? Thank you.